# Correct syntax to write nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This library `RenderHtml` in react native require source variable to be like that

```
{
  html: `
<p style='text-align:center;'>
  Hello World!
</p>`
};
```

In another screen I managed to send the correct object like so

```
html: { html: route.params.index.content.rendered },
```

but here I am inside a for loop so cannot use setState

```
const posts = this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={index}>
        <RenderHtml source={item.excerpt.rendered} contentWidth={width} />
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  ))
```

I tried all of these below, doesnt work

```
source={html: item.excerpt.rendered}
source={'html:' + item.excerpt.rendered}
source=`{html: item.excerpt.rendered}`
source={`html: + $item.excerpt.rendered`}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
source={{html: item.excerpt.rendered}}
```